# Primefaces editor and JQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, editor

I’m trying to use editor from primefaces:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>

    </title>  
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <p:editor/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Now all works fine, but if I add JQuery library, then I get error:

[image: screen]

Comment: How are you adding jQuery library? Primefaces automatically adds jQuery when you use its components so you shouldn't need to add it manually

Comment: Thanks. But if I have JQuery import on header of all pages, and only in some pages I have primefaces elements.

Comment: Did you try with the one bundled with Primefaces?: `<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />`

Comment: You're welcome, I put it on an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primefaces has a bundled jQuery which is included when you use its components. In order to avoid conflicts, you should always include the one bundled with Primefaces so you can also have it in pages where you don't have Primefaces components:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
```